# Doctrine batch processing usage of detach/clear

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Doctrine for batch processing. I am processing a larger number of entities. To save memory i am intersted in using iterable results. In the examples on http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/batch-processing.html Entity-Manager::clear() or Entity-Manager::detach is called inside the batch action.

Correct me if i am wrong:

- If you are processing larger amounts of entities, the entity will
  stay hydrated inside the Identity-Map even after batch process is
  completed.
- This may cause memory issued.
- iterableResults without detach/clear will consume the same amount of memory like hydrating the full result.
- For saving memory you have to call clear/detach

If you do not detach the entity you will run into memory issues if you are processing larger amounts of entities

If you are running the batch processing independently, no problem. However if the batch processing is part of a larger task, this may cause problems.

E.g. the entity is used before batch processing. during batch processing the entity is detached, lateron after batch processing the entity will not be saved to db (as expected).

Is it possible to just detach entities which are only used inside batch processing and not outside?

Are there other solutions than using a separate entity manger or doing batch processing in a isolated environment.

I know that it general it does not make sense to do batch processing synchronously.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only solution is to isolate batch processing. Inside the isolated environment you can use clear/detach without any side effects. However if you process larger amounts of entities memory consumption rises slowly even if you clear the identity map, unset all entities and call the garbage collector by hand. Seems to be the price for using php and doctrine. However this is not a real problem.

If you do batch processing not in an isolated environment, detaching (some) entities/clearing the identity map may cause mayor problems.